# Inequality $|f(x)|' \le c|f'(x)| $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \ni x\mapsto f(x) \in \mathbb{C}$.
I want to know that the following is true:

$$\left| \frac{d|f(x)|}{dx}\right| \le \frac{|f_r f_r'| +|f_i f_i'|}{|f|} \le \frac{(|f_r| + |f_i|)(|f_r'| + |f_i'|)}{|f|} \le c \frac{|f| |f'|}{|f|}\le c|f'(x)|$$
with some positive constant $c$, where $f(x) = f_r(x) + if_i(x) $.

Comment: I think it holds just for the all nonzero $f$

Comment: Ah, my bad. I will correct my answer. today is really not my day.

Comment: More generally, $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq ||f(x)|-|f(y)||$ - we're just taking limits on both sides of this inequality.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: It is the other way around.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks; fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $|f(x)| > 0$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
Then, 
$$ g(x) = |f(x)| = \sqrt{f_r^2(x) + f_i^2(x)} $$ 
is differentiable and by chain rule we have
$$ g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2 f_r(x) f_r'(x) + 2 f_i(x) f_i'(x)}{\sqrt{f_r^2(x) + f_i^2(x)}} = \frac{f_r(x) f_r'(x) + f_i(x) f_i'(x)}{|f(x)|} . $$
Thus, by Cauchy Schwarz, we obtain
$$ |g'(x)| = \frac
{|f_r(x) f_r'(x) + f_i(x) f_i'(x)|}{|f(x)|} \le \frac{\sqrt{f_r^2(x) + f_i^2(x)} \sqrt{(f_r')^2(x) + (f_i')^2(x)}}{\sqrt{f_r^2(x) + f_i^2(x)}} = |f'(x)|. $$

Comment: I believe you have a stray $2$ after the second equality in the second equation.

Comment: @Joel: thx ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

For $h>0$,and using the triangular inequality , we have $\dfrac{|f(x_0+h)|-|f(x_0)|}{h}\leq \left|\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\right|$, now introduce the machine $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0^+}$